# Convert Blob to String so it can be save in csv

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to convert some object into string so I have save it into a csv file.

Right now my code with save this string data into a .csv file and it will work.

```
csvdata = `Date,"First Name","Last Name","Email"
             08.22.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"
             08.21.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"
             08.19.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"
             08.18.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"
             08.17.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"
             08.16.2019,"Simon","Grimm","saimon@devdactic.com"`;
```

My issue is that I need to convert an array of objects into the above.

Searching google I read that I can convert an object into a blob:

So I tried:

```
objToBlob() {
    const obj = {hello: 'world'};
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {type : 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
    console.log(blob);
}
```

But if I do `blob.toString();` and save that into the csv file I get [Object Blob] inside the first cell.

So that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can do this baring in my the the csvData when saved inside the .csv file will work but I need to have an object but it needs to be a string when saved.

How can I do this?

I'm using Angular / Ionic 5 BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the object to comma separated values and then use it just just like you were using the `csvdata`. For example:

```
const obj = {hello: 'world', hi: 'earth'}

const result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => key + ',' + obj[key])
console.log(result.join(" \n"))
/*
"hello,world 
hi,earth"
*/
```

As you can see, the result is just like your csv data

**Update**:
If the data is an array:

```
const car = [ { make: 'Steve', model: 'Celica' }, { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter' }, ];

const obj = {hello: 'world', hi: 'earth'}

const convertToCSV = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(key => key + ',' + obj[key]).join(" \n")

const result = car.map(x => convertToCSV(x)).join()

console.log(result)

/*
result:

"make,Steve 
model,Celica,make,Porsche 
model,Boxter"
*/
```

Comment: Is there a way to change it so it converts data that is wrapped in an array? Example data would be: car = [
    {
      make: 'Steve',
      model: 'Celica'
    },
    {
      make: 'Porsche',
      model: 'Boxter'
    },
  
  ]; ?